# Ruby on Rails - as_json remove some attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a response ready with some attributes. However, I dont want some of them to get passed on to the response. How do I do that? I think I need to use `except` somehow.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> The `:only` and `:except` options can be used to limit the attributes
>   included, and work similar to the `attributes` method.
>
> ```
> user.as_json(only: [:id, :name])
> # => { "id" => 1, "name" => "Konata Izumi" }
>
> user.as_json(except: [:id, :created_at, :age])
> # => { "name" => "Konata Izumi", "awesome" => true }
> ```

Comment: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html#method-i-as_json

Answer (score 1):

You can use `except` parameter of `as_json` like so:

```
2.5.0 :001 > {foo: 1, bar: 2, baz: 3}.as_json(except: [:baz])
 => {"foo"=>1, "bar"=>2}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `only` or `except` for your use case.

Something like below should work:

```
#<Address id: nil, 
          address1: nil, 
          address2: nil,
          city_name: nil, 
          zipcode: nil, 
          phone: nil, 
          state_id: nil, 
          country_id: nil, 
          created_at: nil, 
          updated_at: nil, 
          address_type: nil, 
          latitude: nil, 
          longitude: nil,
          city_id: nil, 
          locality: nil>
```

```
json = address.as_json(only: %i[id 
                                address1 
                                address2
                                locality 
                                city_id 
                                zipcode
                                address_type
                                latitude 
                                longitude],
                           methods: [:city_slug])  # yes, you can use methods as attributes also
```